# How can I with bootstrap-datepicker sanbox limit the selection of days in 1 month?

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I mean this Datepicker:

https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

HTML:

```html
<div id="sandbox-container">
    <label for="date_start">Fecha de inicio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
    <label for="date_end">Fecha de termino</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({});
```

To be more specific, I mean how can I limit the selection to only 1 month, 1-X week or X day that total 1 month, but can not be selected for more than 1 month.

Example:

- Good

  1. **03-01-2019** to **03-31-2019**
  2. **03-01-2019** to **03-01-2019**
  3. **03-01-2019** to **03-20-2019**
- Bad

  1. **03-01-2019** to **04-19-2019**
  2. **03-01-2019** to **03-01-2020**
  3. **02-01-2019** to **03-01-2019**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to test this one, but according to the [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers) and [option](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) it could look like this one

HTML:

```
<div id="sandbox-container" class='start'>
    <label for="date_start">Fecha de inicio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
<div id="sandbox-container" class='end'>
    <label for="date_end">Fecha de termino</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('.start').datepicker();
$('.end').datepicker();
$(".start").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    var startDate = e.date
    var split = startDate.split("-");
    var maxDate = (split[0] + "-31-" + split[2])
    $('.end').data("DatePicker").maxDate(maxDate);
});
```

According to your dateformat like this: MM-DD-YYYY
Hope this helps